# Blocking OS fingerprinting windows server 2008 IIS7

Tags: windows, security, iis-7, windows-server-2008, pci-compliance

We recently had a 3rd party auditor perform a penetration test on our MS 2008 webserver that uncovered remote OS detection vulnerability. It detected the OS as well as version of IIS.

The Auditors recommended: "if Possible, configure the web server so that it does not present identifiable information in the banners"

I've done quite a bit of research and I could not find any easy way that will allow me to quickly block this information from being detected.

Does anyone know of any way to do this? Is this something that needs to be configured/denied on the server level or web application level within the code?

Comment: What do they mean 'banners'? The HTTP response headers? I might ask them for suggestions how to solve the issue anyway.

Answer (score 1):

URLScan is what you'd use back in the IIS 6 days, not sure if it still works with IIS 7 or 7.5.  This is a bit of security by obscurity, and quite honestly most attacks spray everything they have at you and don't care if you are presenting yourself as IIS, they'll throw apache attacks at you or vise-versa.

On top of that there are plenty of things, besides banners that give the server away.  The order at which they present their info in the header is different between IIS, Apache, Weblogic, etc.  httprint is one such utility:  http://net-square.com/httprint/

On top of that you have programs like Satori and p0f that do passive OS identification based on the TCP stack and/or other means.

So yeah, go back to the auditor and ask them what specifically they are recommending, and why!  Taking out the extremely low hanging fruit of the banner is one thing, but honestly, unless you have a script kiddie, with a script that ONLY looks at banner information, you aren't protecting yourself from much of anything.